# How to select 2 tables when using $_GET for page information

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have 2 pages maincontent.php and showcontent.php. When someone visits maincontent.php they are presented with 2 images that they can click on. If they click on image 1 showcontent.php will grab more information about that image and display. This works fine but i would like to be able to grab data from 2 tables not just one.

Here is maincontent.php

```
<?php include('includes/connect.php');?>

<div id="maincontent_holder">
<div id="newest_shows">

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM tv_shows ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";

$result = mysql_query($query);    

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div id='lastest'>";

    echo "<a href='show.php?show_name=$row[show_name]'><img src='$row[show_cover]' width='110' height='160' alt='$row[show_name]'> </a>";



    echo "</div>";
}
?>
</div>


</div>
```

Here is showcontent.php

```
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');
?>
<div id="maincontent_holder">
<?php

$show_name= $_GET['show_name'];

$sql1="SELECT * FROM tv_shows WHERE show_name = '$show_name'
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM show_episodes WHERE show_name = '$show_name'";

    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);    

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {



echo "<div id='cover_img'>";
echo "<img src='$row1[show_cover]' width='110' height='160' alt='$row1[show_name]'>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='show_title'>";
echo $row1['show_name'];
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='show_info'>";
echo $row1['show_info'];
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='show_airs'>";
echo $row1['show_airs'];
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='show_status'>";
echo $row1['show_status'];
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='show_top_adzone'>";



echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='show_desc'>";
echo $row1['show_desc'];
echo "</div>";
//end of show desc
echo "<div id='episode_list'>";




echo "<a href='blaa'>$row1[episode_name]</a>";
echo "</div>";

}
?>
</div>
```

This is the error i get from showcontent.php

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\layout\showcontent.php on
>   line 15

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). Also your code has SQL injection holes.

Comment: Maybe you want a [`join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and not a `union`?  Best MySQL link ever -> http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to something like this

```
$sql1="SELECT tv_shows.*, show_episodes.* FROM tv_shows, show_episodes
       WHERE tv_shows.show_name = '$show_name' and show_episodes.show_name = '$show_name'
       and tv_shows.show_name = show_episodes.show_name";
```

This will do the trick

Comment: That works but the page gets repeated for every row inside of show_episodes?

Comment: @user1947455 : Sorry; can you please explain a-bit what you want

Comment: Basically i want the information from episode_name to display in a list inside the `<div id='episode_list'>` On maincontent.php this works but with the code you gave it makes a copy of the whole page for each row inside of the table show_episodes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are talking of duplicate results then just use `GROUP BY` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You should to use `LIKE '%{$show_name}%'`, before SQL quering do `mysql_real_escape_string($show_name)` for exclude SQL injection. Althow you should be sure of stame collumn structore of `tv_shows` and `show_episodes`. I think it's not use `join`:

```
SELECT s.*, e.* FROM tv_shows AS s JOIN show_episodes e ON e.show_id = s.id;
```